# Python Manage.Py

Tags: python, django

I am very New to Python web development ,so got confuse while learning ,when we create new Project with the command --`django-admin startProject 'ProjectName'`

It Created a project folder in my drive  and then we  create application in it  suppose with the name of "calculator", we start working in it ,

but after some more  requirement we have to  create a new different Project with the Name of the `Hrms` so the question arise for this again we have to run the same command `django-admin startProject 'ProjectName'` and then we have to create application in it or we  can create in it?

Comment: After some more requirements you would create another app not project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One project may have many application in it & you can create app using below code.
`django-admin startapp my_new_app`.
Also you can reuse same app in multiple projects.

For `Hrm` you should create new app instead of new project.

Example : One ERP projects may have many apps like hrm, sales, purchase, inventory etc.. & we can reuse same apps into another ERP projects also if needed.

Hope above clarifications works for you.

Comment: Yes i am getting little bit ,but suppose its not erp project it is different Project like ...restaurants Management...there is relation between them ... then it also come under same umberella,... or again new project will be there then a new application will be there

Comment: You can reuse app only if requirement satisfy. With restaurant project you do not need sales,purchase kind of app but if any core app you have created like for authentication you can reuse them in restaurant project.

Comment: Can we create Same Rest Api Project which is not inter Linked with each Other inside the project Folder or new project need to Created

Answer (score 1):

Project and apps and different see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/)

`django-admin startproject mydjangoproject` creates the project for you,

What you want to do is to create an **app** `hrms` and `caculator` can be apps living under umbrella of one project that is `mydjangoproject`

You should create apps here by `django-admin startapp hrms` and `django-admin startapp calculator` and add it to `settings.py` in your project folder

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ #otherapps here
                  'hrms',
                  'calculator']
```

Answer (score 0):

Start project and start app are very different commands. With the first one you create a project which will have a base structure to work on. The second command is used to create apps which you could classify as controllers. Each app will live in a folder where you will program the business logic and bind endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The app would be a new module in your project, let's say it would be a management system with human resources, financial modules, etc., so you would create an app for each of them to better organize, but nothing prevents creating everything in one app.Create a project only if it is something different.